# Is there a better way to detect what type of user someone is?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Currently we are using the `userType` property on a user to try and figure out what type of user someone is.

However, it seems that this is `PATCH`able and could, in theory, be set to anything.

Is there a more robust way to detect if a user is a `Member`/`Admin` vs. a `Guest`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine if the current user is a member of a given Group, you should use [`/me/memberOf`](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user) instead.

If you want to simply determine if the account is a `Member` or a `Guest`, you can do that by checking `UserType`. While this *can* be changed, it will only accept `Member` or `Guest` as values.

Note: This value can also be `null` if you are using Azure AD Connect and haven't [enabled synchronization of UserType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-change-the-configuration#enable-synchronization-of-usertype) in [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect).

Comment: thanks Marc. /memberOf tells me if they are member of a group, but not if they are a company user or an external user for example.  We are trying to detect if a user is an external user, conference room account etc...